# Check type of generic without generic instance

Tags: typescript

I want to check the type of the generic without an instance of it.

Something like:

```
doThing<T extends Foo | Bar>(someArg: string): T {
  if (T extends Foo) return functionThatReturnsFoo(someArg);
  else return functionThatReturnsBar(someArg);
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I think you can do this if Foo and Bar both descend from the same ancester, and you use that ancestor in the declaration.. Otherwise no. Or at least it shouldn't be. It would be defying the purpose of generics.

Comment: TypeScript's type system is completely [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when the code is emitted to JS.  So that code would become something like `doThing(someArg) { if (T extends Foo) ... }`.  But you can see there's no `T` anywhere in the JS, so there's nothing to check.  If you want to determine `T` at runtime, you need to have some value of type `T` at runtime, and then do some kind of type guard for it.  Can you explain your use case?  I don't even quite understand how you'd want to use `doThing()` in practice.

Comment: @jcalz that makes sense. The use case is that I have two functions that have almost identical logic, but call two different functions internally, with two different return types. I was hoping that I could use generics here, but I think instead I'll have to conditionally call one of the two functions, or pass the target internal function as an argument to `doThing` and have a union return type.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @jcalz, this is impossible because the type system is removed when TS is compiled to JS.

The possible solutions would be:

- create two entirely separate functions with dedicated return types
- pass a flag into the current function to indicate the desired call, and then have the return be a union type
- pass the desired function into `doThing` as an arg, and then have the return be a union type

In my case I just created two dedicated functions with similar logic. It's less DRY, but easier to read and simpler to test.